# Set range of y-axis highcharts API

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts API to generate a line chart, the problem is i can't visualize all the values with the default range of y-axis, because i have bigger and smaller values, so i want to specify the range of y-axis like [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000].

Is there any option or solution to do it ?

Comment: Maybe you can use logarithmic type of your yAxis? http://jsfiddle.net/msaL7yza/

Comment: It's ok thank you Grzegorz Blachliński =)

Comment: Can i force the chart start with 0 value in y-axis using logarithmic type ?

Comment: @Moony Highcharts will get grumpy if you try to set a minimum y-axis value to zero in a logarithmic chart (see http://www.highcharts.com/errors/10), but you can use values such as 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc. to get close as you need to 0 (see http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/msaL7yza/1/).

Comment: Ok thank you Mike =)